# Eclipse IDE does not start

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, eclipse, startup-applications

My computer suddenly shut down due to power failure, while I was working on an Android project using my Eclipse Indigo IDE.

Now, if I start Eclipse, only an empty message dialog (see screen shot) appears and Eclipse does not start. What can I do?

(I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the problem, check the logs folder in the active workspace
It is present in **[workspace_folder]/.metadata/.log** file and post error.

You can clean your workspace and to fix any corrupted configuration file related with workspace. Run the following command from terminal

> eclipse -clean

Comment: Where is actually the .metadata folder located in the Ubuntu file system?

Comment: In your Eclipse workspace, it is a hidden folder, you can see it with command `ls -a` or through Nautilus (View Hidden Files option `Ctlr + H`

Comment: Log message complaining a particular file is not found, but the specified file is there.

Comment: @DUKE Is the problem still existing after `eclipse -clean`, is the problem still persisting? Can you try starting eclipse with a new workspace?

Comment: Yes, I am able to start Eclipse with new workspace. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by ***reinstall Eclipse*** :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall -f -m -u eclipse
```

Perhaps first you need backup your projects/configs.

Comment: OK, how can I perform a complete uninstall? (I think deleting the eclipse folder not enough)

Comment: I think it: `sudo apt-get purge eclipse`

Comment: But I count it better: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall -f -m -u eclipse`