# Eclipse doesn't start on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse

I am facing one issue from many days. Sometime eclipse working fine but sometime eclipse doesn't start. May be some issue in workspace, when I change my workspace then it is working fine. But why it doesn't start on my old workspace.

I also try this [Solution 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161536/eclipse-ide-does-not-start), but no any success.

When I start eclipse it looking like this

[image: Image1]

but after some time it will looking like this

[image: Image2]

I found error from /workspace/.metadata/.log file

```
!SESSION 2012-09-07 11:26:18.718 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -help
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -help

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2012-09-07 11:26:19.993
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl 1 0 2012-09-07 11:26:21.269
!MESSAGE Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-09-07 11:26:28.502
!MESSAGE While loading class "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer", thread "Thread[org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler,1,main]" timed out waiting (5000ms) for thread "Thread[main,6,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 [2]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler,1,main]" is proceeding but "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar" by thread "main".
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.computeClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:2752)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:2728)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1850)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:2705)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2645)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2783)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1915)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getJavaProjectElementInfo(JavaProject.java:1603)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.newNameLookup(JavaProject.java:2282)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.<init>(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1244)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.initialProcess(MonoReconciler.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler.initialProcess(JavaReconciler.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:173)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    ... 56 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.computeClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:2752)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:2728)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1850)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:2705)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2645)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2783)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1915)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getJavaProjectElementInfo(JavaProject.java:1603)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.newNameLookup(JavaProject.java:2282)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.<init>(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1244)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.initialProcess(MonoReconciler.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler.initialProcess(JavaReconciler.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:173)
```

Comment: Try deleting **./eclips** in your Home folder. (Hit Ctrl+H to appear)

Comment: @Naveen I can't find ./eclipse in home fodler

Comment: how long did you wait for it to start?

Comment: @Anwar after second image it never start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your workspace Directory and just delete '.metadata` directory and restart your eclipse.

It will reset your Eclipse setting, once start switch the workspace to your workspace and import your project/s again

Comment: In my case, it wasn't enough, I had to remove the ~/.cache directory as well.

Comment: I'd bold "It will reset your Ecilpse settings" and add "WARNING!"...

Answer (score 7):

Deleting metadata is a very radical way - in essence, it kills workspace (that's why you need to re-import projects).

A more gentle way is to run eclipse with **-clean** flag:

```
eclipse -clean
```

Comment: I also try this but no any solution brother

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute this command in a terminal. Then start eclipse.

The command:

```
rm -r ~/.eclipse
```

Comment: where is ./eclipse file ? i can't found it

Comment: @CapDroid, Just run that above command in your terminal to remove that folder. This folder is by default hidden, so it won't show up normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the same problem as me. It turned out that the default workspace had some problem. If I delete the default workspace (`/home/<name>/workspace`) and then start eclipse then everything works fine. Therefore I changed the default workspace to somewhere else and it worked like a charm.

In eclipse, go to

**File >** switch workspaces and create another workspace somewhere... **Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspace** then in the **Recent workspaces** window, remove your default workspace and apply your newly created workspace

Hope this helps