# Eclipse Compiling After Minimizing Only

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse Mars in Ubuntu 16 and whenever i am trying to compile or even run a java program it doesnt do anything. It just shows its compiling but doesnt do anything even after an hour. Its only if I minimize the eclipse and then restore it then it works. Any Solution?

Comment: from a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) what does this say :    java -version

Comment: java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.metadata` directory and restart your eclipse it will reset setting if no thing changed it may you not install eclipse correctly or suitable  jdk to your eclipse version for eclipse `mars 2` `jdk 8` recommended.

rebooting your device may be recommended i faced an old problem, eclipse not running any thing i delete meta folder restart eclipse no thing running, after rebooting my device and create new project all of my projects run correctly.

see also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184977/eclipse-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu?rq=1).